# How to disable browser feature

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing a project where user gets a conformation page. I want user not to click back or close tab or reload.
Now either I need to disable the browser features or get back button,tab close event, or reload event to java script so that I could take the needed steps to prevent my data to get lost.
I have used this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{
     return "Try This"; 
};
```

But this get called even when I click a button that redirects the page.

Comment: Why use JS? Why not just check if some flag is set in session (?) to skip processing data and just show some warning? Also redirect user to confirmation page to allow user to refresh page without re-sending data.

Comment: I agree with @Justinas - this is down to you managing how your website handles data persistence on the server side.

Comment: If you want to use JS, would [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) be a viable solution?

Comment: it may not. But my scenario is like a eCommerce site. Where user adds his product to cart. he can remove that product in cart but when he progress to payment or confirmation page there he should not be able to click back or close or reload. if this happens the data which is added to cart need to be changed back in db and i thought java script will be the best for this.if u guys know some other way to do please provide some light.

Comment: FWIW: The word is "confirmation," not "conformation" (which is also a word, just not the one you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to have the alert, understanding that the user is ultimately in control and can bypass your alert, then do what you're doing but use a flag that disables it when you're navigating and don't want the alert. E.g.:

```
var warnWhenLeaving = true;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (warnWhenLeaving) {
        return "your message here";
    }
};
```

then in a click handler on the link/button/whatever that moves the user on that you *don't* want this to pop up on:

```
warnWhenLeaving = false;
```

---

In a comment you asked:

> can i know that what user has clicked when alert is generated with this function. That is can i know what user has clicked (leave this page/stay on page)

The answer is: ***Sort of***, but not really; you're almost certainly better off not trying to.

But: If you see your `onbeforeunload` function run, then you know the user is leaving the page and the browser is likely to show them your message. The browsers I'm familiar with handle the popup like an `alert`: All JavaScript code on the page is blocked while the popup is there. So if you schedule a callback via `setTimeout`, you won't get the callback if they leave and you will if they stay:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (warnWhenLeaving) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      display("You stayed, yay!");
    }, 0);
    return "No, don't go!";
  }
};
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/hexuda)

So in theory, if you get the callback, they stayed; if you see an `unload` event, they left. (Note that there are **very** few things you can do in an `unload` event.)

I've tried that on current Chrome, current Firefox, IE8, and IE11: It works on all of those. Whether it will work in the next release of any of them is anybody's guess. Whether it works reliably on mobile browsers is something you'd have to test, and again could change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer its great. But when the alert appears there are two options displayed. When user click stay on this page then its ok else if he clicks leave the page then i want some calculation that need to take place and then i have to redirect him to an appropriate page. can this be done?

Comment: @JLSARP: You can't trap the user on your page. This is a Good Thing(tm). As I said above, all you can do is *"[understand] that the user is ultimately in control and can bypass your alert"*. The alert is there to warn the user that they're doing something that can lose work they've done. It's up to them whether to do that.

Comment: ok it seems this is the possible thing which i can do for now. Thank you for your help

Comment: hai can i know that what user has clicked when alert is generated with this function. That is can i know what user has clicked (leave this page/stay on page)

Comment: @JLSARP: *Sort* of, but not really -- I've added to the answer to explain.